# How does the iPad auto-correct work exactly?

Tags: ipad, auto-complete, autocorrect

When I type in something incorrectly, or if I'm in the middle of typing, the iPad sometimes shows up an auto-correct suggestion. If I click on the suggestion to choose it, it disappears. And then, when I type the word again, the auto-correct  doesn't appear.

How do I get the iPad to actually respond to my auto-correct choice? I tried Googling, but it didn't turn up any results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoCorrect will automatically replace the word unless you cancel it manually by tapping it. (Note the small `×` sign in the suggestion bubble indicating that tapping it will cancel the suggestion.)

So, as soon as an AutoCorrect suggestion appears that you want to use, just hit Space (or insert a punctuation mark) and continue typing.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but is counter-intuitive for a newbie. In fact, the little 'x' sign is at the corner, so I used to think that it shouldn't cancel if I click in the middle :)

Comment: The assumption is that AutoCorrect always knows what’s best for you :) So Apple optimized for the case where AutoCorrect is, in fact, correct. You only have to do the extra work of canceling the “correction” if it’s invalid.

Comment: OK...that's a nice explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are typing and your iPad suggest you something, you should just continue typing or hit the spacebar and your iPad will correct it automatically.

If you take a close look at the suggestions, you'll see a small cross at the right side. Clicking on the suggesting, will make the suggestion disappear since you closed the pop-up.

And once you've closed the popup, it won't be shown in the same word again if you retype the same word.

Comment: Thanks, Michiel, but as I commented on Mathias' answer, it seems to be a counter-intuitive design!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I was having trouble figuring that out. I have to agree, the space bar is a bit counterintuitive, especially when you're used to Android. I do wish iOS would give multiple options like Android does. Each has its strong and weak points. Six of one, half a dozen of the other.